# Valid Parentheses Code Leetcode, What is wrong with my code here-using an array instead of stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.

Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Every close bracket has a corresponding open bracket of the same type.

This is what I tried: Many people used the stack function with few conditionals to solve it but I've used string in an array form with many specific conditionals. What is wrong with my code, and why are people using the stack function-is it a better time complexity?

```
class Solution {
private:
    int i;
public:
    bool isValid(string s) {
        for(i=0;i<size(s);i+2){
            if(s[i]=='(' && s[i+1]!=')'){
                return false;
            }else if(s[i]=='{' && s[i+1]!='}'){
                return false;
            }else if(s[i]=='[' && s[i+1]!=']'){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }               
        }
    }
};
```

Line 6: Char 28: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
for(i=0;i<size(s);i+2){
~^~

Line 17: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^

1 warning and 1 error generated.

Comment: What if `s` is empty? And why loop if you're just going to return on the first iteration?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: You should befriend spaces. Just as with written text, they tend to greatly improve readability.

Comment: A stack allows you to deal with **nested** brackets, e.g. `[[]]`. Your code, even if the bugs were corrected, only deals with **adjacent** brackets, so it might work with `[][]` but not `[[]]`. because in the latter case the first and last brackets are not adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because:

1. It does not solve the given problem.
2. I don't see array vs. stack - you don't even use an array.

Two cents:

- Try to think an algorithm how you can solve the problem
- Try to implement this algorithm

But do the first thing first!

Hint: You need the same *amount* of opening and closing parentheses (and brackets and curly braces) and the correct *order* of them. So for every opening item you need a closing item.

An array cannot work conceptually correct since you don't know how many items there are. This is why you want a dynamic data structure - and because a stack is LIFO...

Take a look at the following string and ask yourself whether your approach would work and how you could achieve your goal:

`([({{[{}]}})])`

The warning from the compiler is not very useful but might go away when you structure the code correctly. Currently you enter a loop in order to return after the first iteration. This does not make sense and compilers try to optimize the code.

Comment: I mean here's an even simpler example: `[[]]`. Just add brackets every time you account for a certain depth, and you've shown the limitations of a regular language. The OP's accounts for first-level `[]` in-sequence, e.g. `[][][]`. The stack is what enables to track your depth while nesting the brackets.